# Bringing values into a loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is almost certainly a duplicate, but I can't find the original - I don't know the search terms to use. Which is why I'm on Stackoverflow instead of Google :)

Anyhow, here's my code:

```
def titleize(say)
  index = 0
  words = say.split
  words.each do |word|
    unless word == "and" || "or" || "over" || "the" || "for"
        word.capitalize!
    end
    if index == 0
        word.capitalize!
    end
    index += 1
  end
  say = words.join(" ")
end
```

Because index is declared before the loop, my `if index == 0` is not working. 
How do I let Ruby know about and use my object index? Also: what is this called?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to use [titleize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/titleize)?  It would capitalize some of your conjunctions, though

Comment: It's a learning exercise where we basically recreate the titleize method, but yes, that would be much easier!

Comment: Note that `word == "and" || "or" || "over" || "the" || "for"` parses as `(word == "and") || ("or") || ("over") || ("the") || ("for")`, which will always return a truthy value.

Comment: Best not to have unnecessary tags (here "ruby-on-rails") as some readers may filter out questions with that tag.

Comment: If you found any the answers helpful, you should select one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `index == 0` is perfectly fine as index is accessible within your loop. Your real problem is probably in this line:

```
word == "and" || "or" || "over" || "the" || "for"
```

This is always `true`-like! What you mean is:

```
["and", "or", "over", "the", "for"].include? word
```

Apart form that there is a method called `each_with_index`, which you can use like this:

```
words.each_with_index do |word, index|
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `with_index`. Your word comparison was busted too.

```
def titleize(say)
  words = say.split
  l = ["and", "or", "over", "the", "for"]

  words.each.with_index do |word, index|
    word.capitalize! if index == 0 || !(l.include? word)
  end

  say = words.join(" ")
end

puts(titleize("hello there for you"))
puts(titleize("hi"))
puts(titleize("for"))
```

Comment: You could also use a unique condition in the loop to avoid code duplication.
`word.capitalize! if index == 0 || !l.include?(word)`

Comment: @Yanis You are correct. I tried to keep it in style with the asker.

Comment: Technically works, but declaring `l` inside of each call of this method creates a lot of garbage. That array would be better as a constant that can be recycled.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how booleans work. The way this is evaluated is:

```
x == 'a' || 'b'
```

Becomes:

```
(x == 'a') || 'b'
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
'b'
```

What you're intending, translated to more idiomatic Ruby, is:

```
def titleize(say)
  say.split.each_with_index do |word, index|
    if (index == 0)
      word.capitalize!
    else
      case (word)
      when "a", "and", "or", "over", "the", "for"
        # Leave lower-case
      else
        word.capitalize!
      end
    end
  end.join(' ')
end

titleize('the time this is a test for the things!')
# => "The Time This Is a Test for the Things!"
```

Comment: One more thing to clarify, `(x == 'a') || 'b'` is not equivalent to `'b'`, it might return `true` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this it is more flexible and more ruby-esque

```
def titleize(sentence,exclusions=[])
  sentence.split.map.with_index do |word,index|
    (index == 0 || !exclusions.include?(word)) ? word.capitalize : word
  end.join(' ')
end
```

For this case i used 'capitalize' without the bang in case any of the words are already capitalized.

```
"Hello".capitalize! #=> nil
"Hello".capitalize #=> "Hello"
```

It will also let you re-use the same list of exclusion or change them as you see fit

Call as

```
exclude = ["and", "or", "over", "the", "for"]
titleize("hello there you are over there", exclude)
#=> "Hello There You Are over There"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns the modification of `say`, but does change the contents of the variable.  It appears that you want to modify the argument, but I'm not sure about that. I will first suggest a way to return the modified value of `say` (but not alter the value of `say`, and then will show how you could change the code to modify the argument.

Notice that I do not employ an index, and use a `case` statement to determine whether words after the first should be capitalized.

**Code**

```
def titleize(say)
  words = say.split
  return "" if words.empty?
  words.first.capitalize!
  return words.first if words.size == 1
  words[1..-1].each do |word|
    case word
    when "and", "or", "over", "the", "for"
    else
      word.capitalize!
    end
  end
  words.join(' ')
end
```

**Examples**

```
say = "and now is the time for all Rubyists to hunker down and code"
titleize(say)
  #=> "And Now Is the Time for All Rubyists To Hunker Down and Code"
say
  #=> "and now is the time for all Rubyists to hunker down and code"    

say = "  "
titleize(say)
  #=> ""

say = " and "
titleize(say)
  #=> "And"
```

**Modifying the Argument**

If you wish to modify the argument `say`, use [String#replace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-replace):

```
def titleize_and_modify_arg(say)
  words = say.split
  str =
  case words.size
  when 0
    ""
  when 1
    words.first.capitalize
  else
    words.first.capitalize!
    words[1..-1].each do |word|
      case word
      when "and", "or", "over", "the", "for"
      else
        word.capitalize!
      end
    end
    words.join(' ')
  end  
  say.replace(str)
end

say = "and now is the time for all Rubyists to hunker down and code"
titleize_and_modify_arg(say)
  #=> "And Now Is the Time for All Rubyists To Hunker Down and Code"
say
  #=> "And Now Is the Time for All Rubyists To Hunker Down and Code"

say = " and "
titleize_and_modify_arg(say)
  #=> nil
say
  #=> " and "
```

Notice that in the second example, `titleize_and_modify_arg` modifies `say` correctly, but returns `nil`.  Of course, the method could be easily changed to return the value of `say`, as well as changing it, if that were desired.

Note also that, in the `case` statement, when `words.siz => 1`, it's `capitalize`, not `capitalize!`, as the latter would return `nil` if the word is already capitalized. `capitalize!` is need for the `else` case, however.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend using `each_index` instead of `each`. See [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-each_index).

Try this:

```
def titleize (say)
  words = say.split
  words.each_index do |index|
    word = words[i]
    unless word == "and" || "or" || "over" || "the" || "for"
        word.capitalize!
    end
    if index == 0
        word.capitalize!
    end
  end
  say = words.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: `each_index` isn't what you want here.